# Many-to-one row updates in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

So I'm trying to update data from a temporary table into a main table.

Let's call these tables temp, and services.

The pseudocode would be something like this...

```
Sort temp by inserted_on

When service_id and location match in both tables:

   If temp.column1 is not null, replace services.column1
   If temp.column2 is not null, replace services.column2
   etc...
```

I've got this bit working, although when I have multiple source rows in the temp table that match the condition, not all fields are being updated.

For example, I might have two rows with identical service_id and location, in one row column1 is null and column2 has a value, and in the next row the opposite is true. I need to update these one by one in the order they came in, and overwrite old data if necessary.

I also need to join the temp table inside the UPDATE to retrieve the keys I'm matching on.

I've tried the below code, but it only seems to be updating certain rows, and I can't quite figure out what the logic is behind it.

I'm not worried about the order, I'm just trying to figure out why it's leaving some blanks when there is data ready to fill the gaps.

```
UPDATE  sloc

    SET     

    sloc.ata =          COALESCE(tmp.ata, sloc.ata),
    sloc.atd =          COALESCE(tmp.atd, sloc.atd),
    sloc.atp =          COALESCE(tmp.atp, sloc.atp),
    sloc.eta =          COALESCE(tmp.eta, sloc.eta),
    sloc.etd =          COALESCE(tmp.etd, sloc.etd),
    sloc.etp =          COALESCE(tmp.etp, sloc.etp),
    sloc.plat =         COALESCE(tmp.plat, sloc.plat),
    sloc.plats_up =     COALESCE(tmp.plats_up, sloc.plats_up),
    sloc.cis_plats_up = COALESCE(tmp.cis_plats_up, sloc.cis_plats_up)

    FROM
            services_locations sloc
            INNER JOIN services svc ON svc.id = sloc.sid
            INNER JOIN ref_tiploc tloc ON tloc.id = sloc.tpl_id
            INNER JOIN trainstatus_tmp tmp ON svc.rid = tmp.rid AND tloc.tpl = tmp.tpl
```

Comment: `COALESCE(...)` only works WITHIN a single row, not across rows. You would have to self-join - is that a step you already took to generate the "temp" table? I'm not sure from how the question is worded currently.

Comment: I'm not trying to coalesce between rows, I'm just using coalesce to update when the source value is not null. What I don't understand is the behaviour of UPDATE when there are two source rows to be 'updated' into one destination row. Basically, I I need the most recent non-null value for each column. Apologies for the poor wording, SQL is not my native tongue...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you run this as a select statement?

Comment: The lower part? Works just fine, duplicate rows where there should be duplicate rows, just need to find a way to insert them appropriately. Thinking about just using a cursor to update one-by-one at this point... Or maybe grouping by each import (as each group won't have dupes).

Comment: Sounds like you need to group first and then COALESCE

Comment: That did cross my mind, do you have any advice for that approach? https://i.ibb.co/85z1Hff/image.png This is essentially what I'm trying to do, if that helps. ROLLUP or something like that maybe?